# 'No module named google.auth.transport.grpc' even though google-auth has been installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, google-assistant-sdk

On my raspberry pi 3, I am trying to run [this code](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py), but I get this error:
No module named google.auth.transport.grpc

I have installed all packages listed in the requirements.txt (on the same github page above), and installed grpcio. I have installed google-auth. I have installed google-assistant-sdk. I have no clue why this module is not working correctly. If I open up python and try: `import google.auth` it gives the same error of "No module named google.auth"

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to run the program with `python -m textinput.py`, which used python 2.x

Using `python3 -m textinput.py` fixed my issue by using python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the version of Python that you are using to run this code. If you installed the module in Python 2.x and try to run it with Python 3.x it will not work, because modules installed on Python 2 are not usable in Python 3 and vise versa.

Comment: How would I determine whether a module has been installed on python 2.x or python 3.x? EDIT: pip3 right? I was using pip :/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while running python scripts that had been running fine until a Google Cloud SDK components update.

Tried removing my project's virtual environment and reinstalling all libraries, but this didn't help.

Ultimately, I followed the page below to completely uninstall the Google Cloud SDK and reinstalled it. All was well again. Not sure what broke.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/uninstall-cloud-sdk